# How to load jar classes as if they were referenced library?

Tags: java, classloader, runtimeexception

I loaded my jar classes with:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(name)
```

in my Plugin loader. But it seems JVM does not register them as a class as if they were referenced, therefore they get garbage collected I get:

> ClassNotFoundException at runtime

How can I register them as if they were a referenced library?
Also, how does JVM load referenced library classes and keeps them registered during JVM lifetime? Can we register runtime loaded classes that way?

Example:

I have an abstract class called AbstractAction in my main project. Then a jar calls x.jar implemented it in ActionImpl. I loaded the jar at runtime and used ActionImpl. But classes that are used in ActionImpl like Utils are not loaded and I get ClassNotFoundException on Utils.

Comment: And where is "Utils" located? Is it on the class path?

Comment: It is in the jar of course. I also loaded Utils with Classloader,but still the same error.